# ZKFinger SDK connect to multiple ZK4500 in C#

Tags: c#, sdk, fingerprint, biometrics

Has anyone connected two or more ZK4500 fingerprint sensor to one PC? I used the ZKFinger SDK.

But when I try to connect from my applilcation, only one sensor is initialized.

Here's my code :

```
if(axZKFPEngX1.InitEngine() == 0) {
   MessageBox.Show(axZKFPEngX1.SensorCount.ToString());
   for(int i=0; i<=1; i++) {
       if(axZKFPEngX1.SensorIndex == i)
       {
          MessageBox.Show("Sensor : " + i + " - Serial Number : " + axZKFPEngX1.SensorSN);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: That may not be supported. Why would you have two fingerprint readers connected?

Comment: in my case, i  need more than one finger reader device and there is only one PC as the server. do you have any idea? @stuartd